# Apply for supercomputing time

Tags: cluster

For testing and running some very intensive C++ number crunching applications, we need to apply for supercomputing time. I would like to get feedback and opinions from you; which calls do you follow, which supercomputing centers do you apply to, etc. As of now I only know DEISA in Europe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you ruled out scaling hosts like Amazon EC2? I'm sure spinning up a bunch of clients there is easier, cheaper, and faster then renting a supercomputer.